# Are there any advantages on skinnable user interfaces?

Tags: skinning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When would you prefer a custom/skinned user interface in a desktop application?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/when-would-you-prefer-a-custom-skinned-user-interface-in-a-desktop-application)

Many applications are skinnable. Firefox, Chrome, WMP, WinAmp, many other media players…

In my opinion this is against the principle of consistency as the applications look different than the OS' UI. Also, this makes helping people that have problems with the software harder as stuff is positioned differently. Next to that, people put too much time in seeking a nice skin; time is holy and you only live once. :)

Why do the developers of these applications do this? What are the advantages of skinnable UIs?